# Website performance that influences user experience

Tags: response-time

I'm looking for some current statistics that reveals data about the majority of users who leave a webpage after they have to wait a certain time until the page starts loading. [Here](http://www.tenfold.com.au/blog/response-time-and-web-page-abandonment)  it says that "57% of online consumers will abandon a site after waiting for 3 seconds for a page to load". But this was from around 2012. 
Does anyone know some more up-to-date data?

Thanks much!

Comment: Are you looking for a specific region? Also what the goal of your website? If you can disregard results from 2012, assuming because they aren't precise enough, then we need more information about your demographic.

Comment: Well, I'm happy for every statistics you can give me, independent from region or goal of website. It only should be from year 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be surprised if there are any stats that recent. Its not something you can get easily. You can not measure abandonment for slow pages with E.G. Google analytics, because the pages aren't loaded yet and thus the stat is not recorded consistently. And it's not like some company is spending a lot of money to get stats every month.

[55 Web Performance Stats You’ll Want to Know](http://blog.radware.com/applicationdelivery/applicationaccelerationoptimization/2014/01/55-web-performance-stats-youll-want-to-know/) (jan 2014) is talking about a two second rule from their [case study about page load time conversions](http://blog.radware.com/applicationdelivery/applicationaccelerationoptimization/2013/05/case-study-page-load-time-conversions/) in may 2013.

Most articles from 2014 you can find in Google still refer to the same source as your example from 2011.